# Positive outward normal derivative = negative inward normal derivative?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Hopf's Lemma states that

Let $Ω$ be a bounded domain in $\Bbb R^n$ with smooth boundary. Let $f$ be a real-valued function continuous on the closure of $Ω$ and harmonic on $Ω$. If $x$ is a boundary point such that $f(x) > f(y)$ for all y in $Ω$ sufficiently close to x, then the (one-sided) directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of the *outward pointing normal* to the boundary at $x$ is strictly positive.

ie

$$ {\partial f \over \partial \nu} >0$$

Can we infer then that the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of the *inward facing normal* to the boundary at $x$ is strictly negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\nu}$ is a notation that is shorthand for
$\nu\cdot\nabla f$. So, clearly, if we consider the inward unit normal derivative,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial (-\nu)}=-\nu\cdot \nabla f=-(\nu\cdot\nabla f)=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial\nu}<0$$